# Handle ArrayIndexOutBoundException

Tags: java

**I am facing Array Index OutboundException when  runs the code..**

*My code here*

```
public void putValuesForDeleteAction(HashMap map ,Object[] colNames,Object[] colValues,Object[] colDataTypes){
        try{
            if(colNames!=null && colNames.length > 0 && colValues!=null && colValues.length >0 && 
                    colDataTypes!=null &&  colDataTypes.length >0){
                int i = 0;
                 i = colNames.length ;
                colNames[i]="LAST_UPDATE_BY";
                colValues[i]=(String)map.get("LAST_UPDATE_BY");
                colDataTypes[i]="VARCHAR2";
                i++;
                colNames[i]="LAST_UPDATE_DATE";
                colValues[i]=(String)map.get("LAST_UPDATE_DATE");
                colDataTypes[i]="TIMESTAMP";

                System.out.println("mapValues is "+map);
            }else{
                // do nothing
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

*Error logs*
2014-09-17 10:47:51.026 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9

Comment: set i to  `i = colNames.length-1` not  `i = colNames.length`. colNames' indices range from 0 to  colNames.length-1. So, colNames[i] is giving you problem.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do but `i = colNames.length` and `i++;` and `colNames[i]="LAST_UPDATE_DATE"; ...` seems pretty wrong to me.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of below code is causing problem.

```
colNames[i] = "LAST_UPDATE_BY";
colValues[i] = map.get("LAST_UPDATE_BY");
colDataTypes[i] = "VARCHAR2";

colNames[i] = "LAST_UPDATE_DATE";
colValues[i] = map.get("LAST_UPDATE_DATE");
colDataTypes[i] = "TIMESTAMP";
```

Once value of `i` is more than the `array length`, it will give this exception.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Eg: suppose `length of any array is 2,` so at max you `can access [0] and [1]`, but if you try to `access [2]`, it will throw the above exception.

**Solution to your problem**
Since you are trying to add new elements in all the three arrays, you must increase or set the size before hand.

Including on @Aryan request, just run below program and analyze

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        // declaring array of size 2, ie it will contain max 2 elements
        String[] myArray = new String[2];

        System.out.println("accessing 1 element");
        System.out.println(myArray[0]);

        System.out.println("accessing 2 element");
        System.out.println(myArray[1]);

        // while accessing 3rd element, it will give error, since size is defines as 2.
        System.out.println("accessing 3 element");
        System.out.println(myArray[2]);


    }
```

> I would suggest you use an **ArrayList** as you won't have to worry
>   about the length anymore. Once created, you can't modify an array
>   size:
>
> An `array` is a container object that holds a fixed number of values
>   of a single type. The length of an array is established when the array
>   is created. After creation, its length is fixed.

Comment: I too know the code cause error .can you explain with code ... ankur-singhal

Comment: @Aryan i have explained enough in my answer, edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException means it does not found any element at index position which you specifying

in your case you first assign object array length to i by  i = colNames.length ;
suppose your array length is 4

means your array last index is 3 because index start from 0,1,2,3 total length 4

so replace
i = colNames.length ;
with 
i = colNames.length - 1 ;

and again you are doing i++ which is again wrong statement

conclusion is ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException occurs when your i > array length

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.arrayCopy to copy existing array to an array of more size and aviod the exception.
Below copyFrom is the original array and copyTo is the destination array of larger size.

> System.arrayCopy(copyFrom, 0, copyTo, 0, copyFrom.length);